# Long switch statement to lookup fifty-something commands

Tags: java

I have a very long `switch` statement which is expected to have nearly 50-55 cases.

```
switch (commandType) {
            case COMMAND_LOGIN:
                command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);
                break;

            case COMMAND_MAKE_READY:
                command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);
                break;

            case COMMAND_MAKE_NOT_READY:
                command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);
                break;

            case COMMAND_MAKE_NOT_READY_WITH_REASON:
                command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);
                break;

            case COMMAND_LOGOUT_WITH_REASON:
                command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);
                break;

            case COMMAND_ANSWER_CALL:
                command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);
                break;

            case COMMAND_HOLD_CALL:
                command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);
                break;

            case COMMAND_RETRIEVE_CALL:
                command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);
                break;

            case COMMAND_END_CALL:
                command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);
                break;

            case COMMAND_TRASFER_SST_CALL:
                command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);
                break;

            case COMMAND_CONSULT_CALL:
                command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);
                break;
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 .
           default :
                command = "";
                break;

        }//end switch
```

It doesn't seem to be something which should exist in this current form, I have gone through some questions here 'but they doesn't seem to help in this condition' I have seen the "strategy pattern", but that also seems to be suitable for the case where i have to execute different method for every case. Kindly guide me how the size of this code can be reduced.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview.SE. I might be missing something but can't this be simply written : `command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);`. Also, this place is about reviewing real code, not some kind of idea.

Comment: thankyou josay, this is my real code, and yes i have got your point.

Comment: that would be the default case, i have just edited the original post. Now there will be a value of "commandType" for which the case will not exist, so if the switch is removed and only command = getCommand(commandType, agentId); is used, a command for an invalid value of "commandType" will also be constructed.

Comment: This is example code right now, or (sorry to say) very bad production code, I would expect every `command` to be calculated differently depending on which case you are in.

Comment: yes i know this is very bad' that's why i need your guidance to make it at-least ok

Comment: Does getCommand contain a similar switch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Enum:

```
public enum CommandType{
        COMMAND_HOLD_CALL(0), 
        COMMAND_RETRIEVE_CALL(1), 
        .....
        COMMAND_RETRIEVE_CALL(55),
        COMMAND_MAX(56),
        ;
        private int commandId;

        private CommandType(int commandId){
            this.commandId= commandId;
        }      
        public int getValue(){
            return this.commandId;
        }
    }
}
```

So your switch statement will reduce to:

```
if(commandType.getValue()<CommandType.COMMAND_MAX.getValue()){ // The range is from  0 to 55
      command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);
}else{
      command = "";
}
```

Any new addition or remove will affect the enum class and nothing else.

Comment: How do you propose map the incoming integer `commandType` to its dual in your enumeration? It appears to me that's where the 'real' validation takes place.

Comment: Is the commandType user input or calculated? You could share the code of commandType and getCommand to help simplify and provide a better solution.

Comment: Is commandType a string or an integer?

Comment: `commandType` is a `string` and it is a user input, so now we need to check weather this `string` exists in `enum` list or not, for that we can use the `valueOf()` method for `enum`.

Answer (score 10):

Giant switch statements are a code smell.  In Java, the usual remedy is to refactor using the [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) recipe.

However, I think your problem runs even deeper.  I raise the following objections:

- Why should this code exist at all?  Shouldn't `getCommand(commandType, agentId);` just return the appropriate result for all values of `commandType`?  Or are there specific command types that you want to disable?  The latter possibility seems disturbing.  If this code is, say, part of a permission-checking system to allow only certain types of commands, I would say that the permission-checking system is woefully underdeveloped.
- Why does `getCommand(…)` return a `String`?  What use could a constant-to-string translation possibly have?

I wish I could give you more constructive suggestions, but unfortunately, you haven't presented much context in the question to allow a deeper analysis.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [fallthrough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough) in order to remove the amount of duplicated code.

```
    switch (commandType) {
        case WHATEV_1:
        case WHATEV_2:
        case WHATEV_3:
        case WHATEV_4:
        case WHATEV_5:
        case WHATEV_6:
        case WHATEV_7:
        case WHATEV_8:
        case WHATEV_9:
            command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);
            break;
        default :
            command = "";
            break;
    }//end switch
```

Now, different situations are possible :

- you have an enum where each value is properly handled and you have this `default` just in case something gets added to the enum : this can be [detected at compilation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999942/how-to-detect-a-new-value-was-added-to-an-enum-and-is-not-handled-in-a-switch).
- if you have an enum where a handful of known values will lead to `command = ""` : it might be better to write these cases explicitely and default to `command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);`.
- if you don't have an enum, *maybe* you should.

In any case, maybe the switch case could be part of the logic in the `getCommand` (and return ""). It only moves the issue more that it solves it but I'd expect a switch to be hidden somewhere in that method.

Comment: thanx josay for elaborate explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, all but the default case have the line

`command = getCommand(commandType, agentId);`

You could create a container list or map of all the possible cases, and if `commandType` does not exist in the container, set the command to an empty string. Otherwise, use the line above to set the command.

Answer (score 1):

@Josay's answer is the best. (I'm just reinforcing it.)

When `COMMAND_LOGIN` etc. are all compile-time constants, decent compilers will generate a branch table, and execution will be extremely fast. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table

I think it is a bad idea to make code more complicated in order to make it shorter. If someone else needs to maintain your code in a few months, they will have an easy time eyeballing your 200-line `switch` statement, without having to think too hard. The only thing I would improve would be to group commands that use the same `getCommand()` variant, as Josay describes, so the code looks like this:

```
switch (commandType) {
    case COMMAND_LOGIN:                 // status-change
    case COMMAND_MAKE_READY:
    case COMMAND_MAKE_NOT_READY:
    case COMMAND_MAKE_NOT_READY_WITH_REASON:
    case COMMAND_LOGOUT_WITH_REASON:
        command = getStatusCommand(commandType, agentId);
        break;

    case COMMAND_ANSWER_CALL:           // call-handling
    case COMMAND_HOLD_CALL:
    case COMMAND_RETRIEVE_CALL:
    case COMMAND_END_CALL:
    case COMMAND_CONSULT_CALL:
        command = getCallCommand(commandType, agentId);
        break;

    case COMMAND_TRASFER_SST_CALL:      // transfer
        command = getTransferCommand(commandType, agentId);
        break;
         . . .
    default:
        command = "";
        break;
}//end switch
```